# Can get album covers but not photos within album (facebook api)

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Below is my code:

```
facebookModule.requestWithGraphPath(
   'me/albums', {
       fields : 'id,name,cover_photo,count,created_time'
    }, 
    'GET', 
    function(graphResp) {
        if(graphResp.success) {
            if(graphResp.result) {
               var albums = JSON.parse(graphResp.result).data;
               //get all album ids.    
               for(x in albums) {
                  var albumId = albums[x].id;
                  //get album covers
                  //var albumCovers= "https://graph.facebook.com/" + (albums[x].cover_photo || 0) + "/picture?access_token=" + facebookModule.accessToken;                  

                  //get photos
                  var photos = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + (albums[x].cover_photo || 0) + "/photos?access_token=" + facebookModule.accessToken;                 
                  console.log(test);
               }                
            }
        } else if(graphResp.cancelled) {
            alert("User Cancelled");
        } else {
            Ti.API.debug(graphResp.result);
        }
     }
);
```

When I do `console.log` I get a list of URLs, which are generated from the graph api. However I am returning an empty json object for each of them - hence no photos from that particular album is shown.

```
var photos = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + (albums[x].cover_photo || 0) + "/photos?access_token=" + facebookModule.accessToken;
```

The graph api call for that album is above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cover_photo` will not give you the url of the cover pic; instead it will give you the **id** of the cover pic. [Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Falbums%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Ccover_photo%2Ccount%2Ccreated_time)

So, when you do : `\{cover-_pic}/photos`- this will give you a json, you'll have to fetch the required image from that. [Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%7Bcover-id%7D%2Fphotos)